# filtering rows using awk

Tags: bash, awk

I currently have a text file with 4 columns that are separated by tabs and I want to filter the file using the 2nd column with awk.

```
awk '$2 ??? {print}' Input_file
```

Input file

`ABCD 123-456-789 BCDE CDEF
ABCD 132678999 BCDE CDEF
ABCD 333-456-789 BCDE CDEF
ABCD 663 667 777 BCDE CDEF
ABCD 183-868-888 BCDE CDEF
ABCD 123 999 999 BCDE CDEF`

Expected Output

`ABCD 183-868-888 BCDE CDEF
ABCD 333-456-789 BCDE CDEF
ABCD 123-456-789 BCDE CDEF`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you only want to filter the 2nd column with `-`, just try `awk -F"\t" '$2 ~/-/ {print}' Input_file`

Answer (score 0):

Your question is not very much clear.

> I want to filter the file using the 2nd column with awk.

Below I have used awk to filter rows based on field/column value.
Example: I have filtered rows which contains the vale 123.
Likewise you can use it to filter with any value.

```
user@server> cat random
ABCD 123-456-789 BCDE CDEF
ABCD 132678999 BCDE CDEF
ABCD 333-456-789 BCDE CDEF
ABCD 663 667 777 BCDE CDEF
ABCD 183-868-888 BCDE CDEF
ABCD 123 999 999 BCDE CDEF
user@server> cat random | awk '/123/'
ABCD 123-456-789 BCDE CDEF
ABCD 123 999 999 BCDE CDEF
user@server>
```